# How to programmatically refresh browsers after new deploy of Angular2 application

Tags: angular, browser-cache

I found that clients are often running in outdated code. I even have the logic to detect whether they are outdated: I placed a timestamp as a constant in a .ts file (because writing to environment.ts is more complidated -- with its dedicated .ts, I can rewrite the whole file any time), and also place it in the database. I did a location.reload(true) when the database is newer, but the client is still using old .ts files (and caught itself in an infinite loop of refreshing).

Manually, control-F5 will make the code see the new constant in the modified .ts. But how can I do it in code?

I read many solutions about using random numbers in resource names, but it doesn't apply to angular components.

Comment: What you mean old TS? you are not compiling ?

Comment: There is no difference between location.reload(true) and F5, so it does need to have another reason. Let us see how you check for an new timestamp

Comment: I ng build and deployed. But the browsers are still using the old TS files.

Comment: @Doomenik I'm positive the timestamps are correct, because I console.log them all over the place. The timestamp is created as the first stamp of the build process, and when a client find that it has a timestamp later than the database, it will update database, so other clients will notice (that database is later than their own timestamp) and refresh itself.

what is curious is that after location.reload(true), which I can see the browser reloading, the client is still using the old TS files, printing out the old timestamp.

Comment: even more curious, I added window.open(location.href, '_blank'); and nothing happens. The line is executed but nothing.

Comment: chrome network trace confirms that nearly all the chunks are from memory cache or disk cache.

Comment: Its well documented here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=443462

Comment: Wow! a 2014 bug with status wontfix! Is there anything I can do in javascript  that can circumvent this?